# Escaping quotes in echo for mysql input

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I am preparing data to update product descriptions into MySQL database from a CSV file. Sometimes I have data with Single and double quotes. However I'm facing trouble to input data when data have single quotes or double quotes. For Example

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

echo -n '\"QB 99307 THUG LIL' BIG TIME BOX CALL\", \"'
```

is giving an error.

I tried escaping `'` with `\'` after LIL, but it didn't worked. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
echo -n "\"QB 99307 THUG LIL' BIG TIME BOX CALL\""
```

---

Based on [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21644688/escaping-quotes-in-echo-for-mysql-input/21644719#comment32711696_21644719), use this:

```
system("echo -n \"\\\"QB 99307 THUG LIL' BIG TIME BOX CALL\\\", \\\"\" >> " . FILE_NAME);
```

Comment: I'm using echo inside a system command of my Perl script. It seems, double quotes are mismatching in my script.

    system("echo -n "\"QB 99307 THUG LIL' BIG TIME BOX CALL\", \"" >> " . FILE_NAME);

Comment: I appreciate your help, but getting mysql error while failing to escape 2.25" for the following string with the above command...

"Fobus TTRB214 Roto-Holster System Tactical Thigh Rig Belts to 2.25" Poly Blk"

Comment: If you're connecting to SQL servers, try using prepared statements.

Comment: I cannot use them at this stage now and it would take few days to re-write the code. Instead I can fix this error. Please guide me

Comment: @doubledecker Even if I suggest you method to solve this error, it'll arise again for some different string. It would be better and safer to take a day or two to learn about prepared statements and use them.

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
`echo -n "QB 99307 THUG LIL' BIG TIME BOX CALL " >> FILE_NAME`;
```